# How write macro to avoid redefine?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have the follow macro:

```
#define my_add_property(ret, name, value) \
  object tmp; \
  tmp = *value; \
  add_property(ret, name, &tmp);
```

Now I use the macro in the follow function:

```
void func() {
  object *ret;
  my_add_property(ret, "key", my_func1());
  my_add_property(ret, "value", my_func2());
}
```

It will have `make error`: `tmp` is redefined.

So I want to use `object tmp##name`, but if name is `"key"`, `tmp##name` will be `tmp"key"`. I should do how write the macro that make `tmp##name` to `tmpkey` not `tmp"key"`? thanks!

Comment: I love it how people go out of their way to make code hard to read and maintain. Do they like a hard life?

Comment: Is having `return` as the name of a parameter a good idea?

Comment: Why not just use `add_property(ret, "key", my_func1())`? A pointer to `tmp` becomes meaningless once `func()` finishes. What is the point of having `my_add_property()` in the first place? Maybe what you really want is: `object *tmp = malloc(sizeof(object)); *tmp=*value; add_property(ret,name,tmp)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new scope inside your macro, such that `tmp` is only live for a short amount of time by wrapping the implementation in a `do {} while(0)`, for example:

```
#define my_add_property(return, name, value) do { \
  object tmp;                                  \
  tmp = *value;                                \
  add_property(return, name, &tmp); } while(0)
```

Comment: The usual form is `#define MACRO(args) do { something; } while (0)`. That way, you won't get nasty surprises if you somehow decide to elide brackets after `if`/`else`/`while`/`for`, and you'll get slightly better error messages when using such macros in an expression. That said, there is no reason whatsoever to not use a `static inline` function instead.

Comment: @slugonamission Thanks a lot, it is OK.

Comment: @thinkerou, I think there need to add `(void)tmp;` right after call to `add_property(...)` for release temporary variable `tmp` placed in stack.

Comment: @imbearr maybe, I will use `do {} while(0)`.

Comment: @imbearr What do you mean? At the end of the block, the allocated space of `tmp` (register, stack, heap, or otherwise - none of these things exist in C) may be reused by the compiler.

Comment: @Rhymoid, _register, stack, heap, or otherwise - none of these things exist in C_ Do you really think so? Anyway if block end it is enough for release `tmp` in any cases - so I have no questions.

Comment: @imbearr None of the C standards have such concepts. Therefore, they don't exist in C per se.

Comment: @imbearr: they exist in most implementations, but are implementation details, not concepts in C. An implementatin is free to do these things differently.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, thank you, now I understand this view. But I have question: is end of block enough to guarantee release of `tmp` or may be need to use `(void)tmp;` to force compiler do it anyway?

Comment: The end of the block is enough.